# Building my portfolio webpage in react but components won't render for some reason

Tags: html, reactjs, webpack, rendering, react-dom

I'm trying to build a simple portfolio website using react. So far, the base html is the only thing that is rendering. I'm in the early stages so I built a very small component to make sure it was rendering properly but nothing besides the html has rendered. I don't get any errors when i run the webpack dev server. Below is my code.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Engineering Portfolio</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Portfolio">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="root">
            <h1>Components should render here</h1>
        </div>
        <h1>
            HELLO WORLD.   --  Look for navbar above
        </h1>


    </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import React from 'react';

document.body.innerHTML = '<div id="root"></div>';

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App />);
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./src/components/Navbar/navbar";

const App = () =>{
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Navbar/>
        </div>
    )
}
export default App
```

navbar.js

```
const Navbar = ()=>{
    return (
        <h1>react is rendering this 'navbar'</h1>
    );
}
export default Navbar
```

Originally i was using reactDom render before realizing that its been deprecated. I switched to using createRoot from the react documentation but have seen no changes. I simplified the intended component to simply show a div with a h1 tag to show me its working. So until I see the specific h1 tag, i know react isn't working as i want.

Comment: You haven't shared your webpack config (and also please don't share images of code) but if you are not linking the JS to the HTML it's not going to work.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I managed to get it working. Turns out my webpack was missing the htmlwebpackplugin. Everything started to render after I used it!